# setNilValueForKey not called in Core Data Utility Tutorial

Tags: core-data, key-value, key-value-coding

Apple's [Core Data Utility Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/06_runClass.html) recommends implementing `setNilValueForKey:`and testing its effect:

> Use key-value coding to set the process ID to nil. Build and run the utility. Again, what happens? And finally, comment out the setNilValueForKey: method and test once more.

I attempt to set the process ID to nil with this code: `[run setValue:nil forKey:@"processID"];` but this doesn't call `setNilValueForKey:`.  Why not?

Here's my implementation; the NSLog statement I added never appears.

```
- (void) setNilValueForKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSLog(@"setNilValueForKey: %@",  key) ;
    if ( [key isEqualToString:@"processID"] ) {
        [self setValue:@0  forKey:key ] ;
    }
    else {
        [super setNilValueForKey:key] ;
    }
}
```

I found [similar stackoverflow discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392142/what-values-am-i-supposed-to-be-getting-from-apples-core-data-utility-tutorial), but none answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `setNilValueForKey:` is never called if the dynamically generated accessor methods are used.

If you provide a custom setter method for the "processID" property in "Run.m":

```
- (void)setProcessID:(NSInteger)processID
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"processID"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:@(processID) forKey:@"processID"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"processID"];
}
```

then

```
[run setValue:nil forKey:@"processID"]
```

causes `setNilValueForKey:` to be called.

That is only what I experienced by try and error, I do not have official references for this. But the "Core Data Utility Tutorial" exists since Mac OS X 10.4, where dynamically generated accessor methods (as far as I know) did not yet exist. So it *could* be that the parts about `setNilValueForKey:` where not updated for 10.5. But that is pure guessing on my side.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I'll leave feedback using Apple's "Did this document help you?" Document Feedback.

Comment: @ghettopia: You are welcome. -  You can also submit a bug at bugreport.apple.com, there is a special category "Documentation".